# webpack - Property context does not exist on type NodeRequire

Tags: typescript, webpack, webpack-3

I want to use:
`require.context('../images/', true, /\.(png|ico|svg|jpg|gif)$/)`

but I get the following error:

> Property context does not exist on type NodeRequire

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Just install the typings for `webpack-env`

```
npm i @types/webpack-env -D
```

Comment: Please keep in mind that this alone is not enough, you also need to do JoaquinBu's answer below this.

Comment: @laszlo-horvath
 If you have a Typescript project

Comment: Or `yarn add @types/webpack-env --dev`

Answer (score 25):

And in tsconfig.json add it in the types property
example:

```
 {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "./dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "allowJs": false,
    "types": [
      "node",
      "webpack-env" // here
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "src/index.ts"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the above solutions, you can also add an interface for this function manually just like this:

```js
//index.d.ts

declare global {
    interface NodeRequire {
        /** A special feature supported by webpack's compiler that allows you to get all matching modules starting from some base directory.  */
        context: (
            directory: string,
            useSubdirectories: boolean,
            regExp: RegExp
        ) => any;
    }
}
```