# Property 'context' does not exist on type 'NodeRequire'. TS2339

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types, typescript-typings

I can't clear this error. I've installed and reinstalled webpack types but can't figure out how to make this work. Is there a way to clear or bypass this error?

**Error**

TypeScript error in /app/src/components/MoviePage/MoviePage.tsx(9,11):

Property 'context' does not exist on type 'NodeRequire'.  TS2339

**Code with error**

```js
const movieThumbImages = importAll(
  require.context("../../assets/moviePosterImages", false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/)
);
```

**Function**

```js
export const importAll = (r: any) => {
  return r.keys().map(r);
};
```

**package.json**

```js
{
  "name": "movie-hunt",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.24",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.20",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.19",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.9",
    "@types/react-router": "^5.1.16",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.8",
    "@types/webpack-env": "^1.16.2",
    "webpack-env": "^0.8.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here you can find the answer:
[webpack - Property context does not exist on type NodeRequire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48935663/webpack-property-context-does-not-exist-on-type-noderequire)

1. npm i @types/webpack-env -D
2. add `"webpack-env"` into `types` in tsconfig.json like:

   ```
   {
     "compilerOptions": {
       ...
       "types": [
         "node",
         "webpack-env" // here
       ]
     },
     ...
   }
   ```